# Can't find any log file explaining why Eclipse closes/crashes

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, crash, ubuntu-14.04, crash-reports

After last Ubuntu 14.04 kernel update (current one: 4.4.0-36-generic) when I open Eclipse (Luna) in a matter of few seconds it closes or freezes and then closes (I can be simply editing a comment, or even stop typing for some seconds and then it happens, so I think it can't be related to the code itself).

I personally prefer when it freezes first, so it gives you some seconds to mentally prepare of what is about to happen with your last-hour work.

No clue on system.log or /.../my_workspace/.metadata/.log of what is happening.

Where could I look to try to understand what is happening?

Is it possible that Eclipse closes without leaving any clue/crash-report of why is it doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying a lot of possible solutions because Eclipse was crashing every 10 minutes I've found this:

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=465693

According to this bug report it is not an Eclipse problem but an Eclipse-JRE relationship problem.

Since I've modified several lines in **eclipse.ini** I cannot be sure about the solution, but it seems it was adding this line on it:

**-XX:-UseLoopPredicate**

I've been without crashes for more than 1 hour so far. However I'll wait at least one or two days before assuming this solution really works.

EDIT/UPDATE:  Confirmed; it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever eclipse crashes you will get hs_err_pid4612.log this kind of file 
inside eclipse folder.

For fixing this issue :
Add this to eclipse.ini file:
-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not getting that log (nor any other *.log in Eclipse folder).

Comment: Go to workspace  there is a .log file in the .metadata directory inside which often contains a number of stack traces from the Eclipse internals.

Comment: I appreciate your spent time but please read my question completely: As I indicate in it, no information is added to that log neither before nor after the crashes.